# Question migrated from StackOverflow with (or without?) OP account

Tags: support, migration

Sometimes I see questions migrated from StackOverflow, such as [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/596874/56940), where the user's account on Cross Validated seems (kind of) inactive.

Is the Cross Validated account of the user in the link actually active? If not, If I answer this question, is the OP still able to accept/upvote my answer?

Comment: It looks like that any time a Q is migrated to a site where the OP doesn't have an account.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at this user's StackOverflow account, it is new as of today. He does not seem to have any other accounts in the SE system. The way this user is shown on CV is standard when he didn't yet make a user himself. He might very well visit here now after the migration ... and then the account could be active. It's up to him.

Comment: thanks. But what if the OP never visits CV?

Comment: There is no way to know! As this user is new to the SE family as of today, how could we possibly know if he is one-time, drive-by user, or a new useful contributor? You might help to increase somewhat the probability of the second option, by writing a useful answer NOW. New users need some incitement and help to understand the rules!

Comment: The answer should be taken in general (+1). But specifically for the question in hand, it seems the account holder is now a member of this community since today.