# What happens with questions of unregistered users?

Tags: support, new-users

I found an interesting question, posed by a user who has not registered yet. I am afraid the user may have lost access (account confirmation lost in spam, typo in email address, user on holidays, got sick, or whatever reason) and eventually gets deleted.

1. Will the question survive if it gets an answer?
2. If yes, will it still be possible to comment?
3. Do votes on the question / answers to such a question make a difference here?

Comment: Are we talking about unregistered users or questions migrated from other SE sites with OP not signed in here?

Comment: WLOG, I can tell that unless the post is really lacking any quality based query which elicits downvotes and subsequent closing (and thereby plausible deletion later), the question would be there assuming the user is not logged in to delete their own post. Handle it the way you would have with another regular post, sans OP's interaction (s).

Comment: A user who is unregistered. I wrote "has not registered yet" because the question is fairly new, and the only question the usee has posted

Comment: @User1865345-solidarityMods, you will post your second comment as an answer, won't you? What do you mean by wlog - without loss of generality? Thanks for the quick comment!

Comment: Ute, this is the way, in general, the questions work. Specific cases may differ (that's why _wlog_). But in all respect, you can interact (comment, answer, suggest an edit) in usual way. As for OP being unregistered, it won't lead to the question being closed or deleted altogether.

Comment: In fact, day in and day out, we would get a post from an unregistered user. It doesn't matter much for the longevity of the question.

Comment: Thank you for clarification about wlog @User1865345-solidarityMods :-) (I understood it as "a special case represents generality", like in math proofs) and for reassuring it is safe to answer. The particular question already has 3 upvotes.

Comment: Such users are generally less committed to the site, its policies, & their own question.  They are less likely to respond to comments & less likely to accept an answer, etc.  Occasionally, they will drop a Q & never show up again.  That said, there is otherwise no effect of the asker's registration status on anything.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica, good to know that the questions don't disappear. I admit to be one of these users ;-) - had to create a new user to drop a couple of answers (because the original on cv seemed defunct - planned to merge with my SE account later), and found everything gone after a week, when I detected the confirm-your-email mail in spam.

Comment: related https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6420/56940

Answer (score 4):

Turning my comment as a brief answer: as has also been noted by gung - Reinstate Monica, the status of registering of a user doesn't have any bearing on the questions posted by the said user. Unless the quality of the post elicits downvotes and subsequent closing (with a possible [deletion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) thereafter) or the user, if they bother to visit again, decides to delete the post before receiving any positively voted answer, the question would "survive".

Handle the post the way you handle any other regular post. There is no necessity of a different treatment. If someone doesn't visit again to provide further feedback/clarification, there is nothing you can do. Apart from that, this is business as usual.

Comment: In short: registration status of the user has no influence whatsoever on questions - good to know!

Comment: Yes, Ute. Specific cases may need more attention or discussion. But in general, this is what it is :-)